# I'm upgrading my RAM, and have conflicting results from CPU-Z and CrucialScan; how many RAM slots do I have? Also, 4x4GB vs. 2x8GB?

Tags: memory, hardware-rec

**I figured it out!** I managed to get under my keyboard finally, and indeed, I only have two DIMM slots. I will soon purchase 2x8GB RAM.

---

I'm upgrading my Sager NP6165 from 8GB to 16GB RAM (see justification at the bottom) and having trouble figuring out how many card slots I have. Here's an image from underneath the laptop:

[image]

and the CPU-Z scan results:

[image]

[image]

The "SPD tab in the CPU-Z scan gives specs in the drop-down menu for 4 separate slots -- 1 and 3 are active, but 2 and 4 have everything grayed out (I evidently have 2 4GB cards). I've seen from youtube that **similar models** often have **2 more RAM card slots underneath the keyboard**, which haven't yet figured out how to take off. But CrucialScan told me I have 2 slots (**quote**: "Slots:2 (2 banks of 1)"). What do you guys think?

Also, if it turns out I have 4 slots, would you guys recommend 4x4GB or 2x8GB cards (any performance differences)? And if I were to do 4x4GB, could I just add the 2 extra 4GB cards without replacing the old ones/is there anything complicated I'd have to do to get the BiOS to recognize the additional cards? Thanks in advance.

---

**Justification**: Almost all of my 8GB of RAM is usually "In Use"/"Standby" (I run a lot of programs concurrently, leave things open; although I still try to minimize usage e.g. with The Great Suspender extension for Chrome). When I try to run Lightroom/Photoshop I can have some major speed issues, and sometimes even get "out of memory" messages. I already have an SSD drive, which I know is the best choice for improving OS performance and speed of read/write-intensive software.

Comment: Be sure you are running out of actual physical system memory instead of just virtual memory.  Any event you only have 2 slots since you don't want to confirm the modules undernearth the keyboard.  Its unlikely your system will boot with 8GB modules.

Comment: "Its unlikely your system will boot with 8GB modules."


Why is that? So you'd recommend confirming the 2 additional slots and buying 2 new 4GB cards? Will read up on system vs. virtual memory; just opened another stackexchange thread.

Comment: You provided no specifications on the hardware, so I am going off the fact, it came with 4GB modules instead of a 8GB module

Comment: I use Resource Monitor (Windows 7) which shows just "Physical Memory", evidently. So pretty sure I do need the upgrade.

Comment: So the memory module is specific to card size? I can try to find further hardware info for you; I currently have 2 4GB cards if you didn't catch that.

Comment: Why don't you confirm, the amount of modules your system actually supports, then update this question.

Comment: Will try again to get underneath the keyboard if no one has an answer (there were 2 questions here; 1 was whether the results from CPU-Z or CrucialScan should be trusted).

Comment: You provided us zero information about your hardware.  I trust what I can see with my own eyes.  I don't use software to determine what memory I have installed or how many DDR3 modules my system supports.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll open her up. (excuse my ignorance). But what *type* of hardware information do you need re:will 8GB cards work? Also, would be grateful if you could direct me to some resources explaining the complications here; the DIY RAM upgrade threads I've read don't seem to have any disclaimers/warnings about my hardware potentially not recognizing bigger cards.

Comment: Here are screenshots of the CPU-Z scan if it's worth anything: http://imgur.com/a/uhMZP

Comment: What cards?  Your machine is a laptop, is can only use, laptop DDR3 memory.  Laptop DDR3 only comes in one size.  The proper technical terms are important, by using the word "size", I am thinking physical size.  If you want to talk about the capacity, the amount of storage the memory provides,use that term instead.

Comment: What is the model and manufacturer of your laptop?

Comment: It's a Sager NP6165. And @Ramhound ok that was the confusion; to me size/"bigger"/"smaller" implicitly references capacity -- I mean of course I have to get one in a compatible physical format/correct number of pins. For example if I wanted to upgrade my HDD from 500GB to 1TB I would certainly say I'm getting a "bigger" one, why would anyone use that language in reference to its physical size? And I thought the physical RAM piece was claled a "card"; apparently it is chip/module?

Comment: You want to purchase memory modules, specificially laptop DDR3 SDRAM` modules.  A HDD with 1TB has a larger storage capacity then a HDD with 500GB.

Comment: The capacity and type supported is dependent on the cmos/bios software, motherboard design, and CPU design (modern cpus have the memory controller on die). So there is no one answer to the question: this is why you need to specify the hardware and check the documentation for that model (and *revision*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are only 2 DIMM slots.

It may help if you go into the documentation (manual or online web doc) for your computer / manufacturer and find the compatible RAM modules for your specific machine.

Do yourself a favor and go to Amazon and find DDR3 Laptop RAM (2x8GB), if your laptop **POSTS** after you install it, you should be good to go. They have a great return policy in case it does not work.

If your laptop  **does not**  POST, then the RAM is incompatible.

Best of luck.